# swift pass images from collection view controller to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue

i have downloaded set of users photo from firebase and view it as collection view (instagram like) 
but im trying to enlarge the photo clicked in another view controller using segue but its not working. 
Any  thoughts about my code:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController{
    var photoThumbnail: UIImage! 
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileCollectionViewCell
        cell.imageCollection.downloadImage2(from: currPosts[indexPath.row].photoUrl)
        cell.imageCollection.image = photoThumbnail
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "photoViewSegue", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var destViewController : EnlargePhotoViewController = segue.destination as! EnlargePhotoViewController
        destViewController.labelText = "test"  //**** this works
        destViewController.myImage = photoThumbnail //**** this doesnt work 
    }

}
```

and the collection view cell is:

```
class ProfileCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageCollection: UIImageView!

}
```

lastly the target viewController:

```
class EnlargePhotoViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var enlargedPhoto: UIImageView!

        var labelText = String()
        var myImage: UIImage!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

           myLabel.text = labelText
            enlargedPhoto.image = myImage
        }
    }
```

Comment: *its not the complete code but i share the most important lines

Comment: its hard to know how to answer the question without seeing all the code, in the extract provided the variable photoThumbnail is never set and always nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change to this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ProfileCollectionViewCell

    photoThumbnail = cell.imageCollection.image
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "photoViewSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your only goal is to get the image of the selected cell, this can be done more efficiently. All you have to do is read/write to the cells imageView property, photoThumbnail is never set so  always nil, just modify this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileCollectionViewCell
    cell.imageCollection.downloadImage2(from: currPosts[indexPath.row].photoUrl)
    //cell.imageCollection.image = photoThumbnail <-- No need of this
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


  // get the correct cell on select 
   if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ProfileCollectionViewCell
   {
    photoThumbnail =  cell.imageCollection.image <-- finally assign the imageview to image
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "photoViewSegue", sender: self)
   }
}
```

for safer retrieve the image, use like

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if let getImage = myImage
        {
        myLabel.text = labelText
        enlargedPhoto.image = getImage 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**First View Controller**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
            let objstory = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        objstory.strd = imageView.image
        _ = self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objstory, animated: true)

        }
    }
```

**SecondViewController**

```
 var strd:UIImage!
@IBOutlet weak var imgprof: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imgprof.image = strd


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController{
    var photoThumbnail: UIImage!
    var selectedPhotoURL: NSUrl!


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collection_cell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileCollectionViewCell
        cell.imageCollection.downloadImage2(from: currPosts[indexPath.row].photoUrl)
        cell.imageCollection.image = photoThumbnail
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedPhotoURL = currPosts[indexPath.row].photoUrl
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "photoViewSegue", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        var destViewController : EnlargePhotoViewController = segue.destination as! EnlargePhotoViewController
        destViewController.labelText = "test"  //**** this works
        //make image from selected url or pass url and download it in EnlargePhotoViewController
        let downlodedImage = yourMethodToDownload(selectedPhotoURL) 
        destViewController.myImage = downlodedImage //**** this will work work 
    }

}
```

Comment: but ive already download the image and if i download it again that would be bad memory managment. thanks though